# QGIS Script Editor to get operations between raster and float number

Tags: raster, pyqgis

I am looking for developing python codes mainly for working with raster data, in particular satellite imagery from Landsat. I need to write a script (into the QGIS Script Editor) to make operations between Raster data and number (float). I know how to define the Raster but I don't know how to define the number to make it work. I am working with the last version of QGIS Essen 2.14 and I tried the following code to make a simple sum between a raster and number but it doesn't work:

```py
##RED=raster
##a=number 0.5
##XXX=output raster

from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

# Get layer object
layer1 = processing.getObject(RED)
# Get number
number1 = a

def xxx (RED,a,output):
    entries=[]

    #define raster 1 ("RED")
    raster1=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    raster1.ref='RED@1'
    raster1.raster=RED
    raster1.bandNumber=1
    entries.append(raster1)

    #define number1 ("a")
    number1=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    number1.ref='a'
    number1.float=a
    entries.append(number1)


    #XXX Processing
    calc=QgsRasterCalculator('("RED@1"+a)',output,'GTiff',RED.extent(),RED.width(),RED.height(),entries)
    calc.processCalculation()

xxx(layer1,number1,XXX)
```

Comment: Try replacing `QgsRasterCalculator('("RED@1"+a)'` with `QgsRasterCalculator('("RED@1"+' + a + ')'`.

Comment: by replacing with '("RED@1"+'+a+')' I get the following message: "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects"

Comment: Ah, forgot that it needs to be converted to string. Try replacing `a` with `str(a)`, so that it reads `QgsRasterCalculator('("RED@1"+' + str(a) + ')'`

Comment: The following layers were not correctly generated.
XXX
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

Comment: I got it it is:

Comment: ##RED=raster
##a=number 0.0
##XXX=output raster

import numpy
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

layer1 = processing.getObject(RED)
number1 = a

def xxx (RED,a,output):
    entries=[]
   
    raster1=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    raster1.ref='RED@1'
    raster1.raster=RED
    raster1.bandNumber=1
    entries.append(raster1)
    
    number1='a'
            
    calc=QgsRasterCalculator('("RED@1"+' + str(a) + ')',output,'GTiff',RED.extent(),RED.width(),RED.height(),entries)
    calc.processCalculation()
    
xxx(layer1,number1,XXX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it:

```
##RED=raster
##a=number 0.0
##XXX=output raster

import numpy
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

# Get layer object
layer1 = processing.getObject(RED)
# Get number
number1 = a

def xxx (RED,a,output):
    entries=[]

    #define raster 1 ("RED")
    raster1=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    raster1.ref='RED@1'
    raster1.raster=RED
    raster1.bandNumber=1
    entries.append(raster1)

    #define number1 ("a")
    number1='a'

    #XXX Processing
    calc=QgsRasterCalculator('("RED@1"+' + str(a) + ')',output,'GTiff',RED.extent(),RED.width(),RED.height(),entries)
    calc.processCalculation()

xxx(layer1,number1,XXX)
```

Comment: Way to go, nice one! :)